# How to restore Window 7 logon screen?

Tags: windows-7

Hello Everyone I need your help... Last time I login as administrator and have change my domain in a renamed workgroup into something like "svc" before it was in a domain "svc.edu" and then I enter a different username [ffv] and password [123456] and the pc restart...The problem is that after it restarted the internet connection is now ok then when I try to restore it back to register is to a domain "svc.edu" and login as username [ffv] it replies an error "That it has a stale conflicting account." and the login screen when the pc restarted looks like the picture this:

[image]

I want to restore it back into this:

[image]

(The image is not mine just a sample...)

Comment: Are you connected to the svc.edu domain while you are trying to rejoin it and login?

Comment: Yes.,. would it be possible if I did this one http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-CHqROpZuyOg/Tq5pa6NiyHI/AAAAAAAADoc/BA5QbeMRL1E/s1600/secpol.PNG

Comment: @techie007 Yes.,. would it be possible if I did this one http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-CHqROpZuyOg/Tq5pa6NiyHI/AAAAAAAADoc/BA5QbeMRL1E/s1600/secpol.PNG

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you left the domain.

When your computer was in the domain your account name was `svc.edu\ffv`. If the computer was set to log onto that domain by default then you never had to explicitly type the first part. Yet it is still there.

When you left the domain you reverted to local logins. This means that typing `ffv` into the username field now translates to `svc\ffv`, which is a completely different user with different credentials.  (The svs in svc\ffv is the name your set as your computer name).

To revert to domain logins you need rights to add your computer back to the domain. Usually these rights are reserved to the domain administrators. Which comes down to mailing or phoning them and and telling them what you did. Depending on how things are set up they then can fix that remotely or they will tell you to take the laptop to IT.

(Personally I would tell people the last. If someone has messed with their computer then I am not typing a domain admin password on that computer. I would tell the user to back up data, reimage the whole PC and re-add it to the domain.)

Comment: would it be solve using secpol.msc http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-CHqROpZuyOg/Tq5pa6NiyHI/AAAAAAAADoc/BA5QbeMRL1E/s1600/secpol.PNG